# Verifying if a String is fully supported in a specific codepage

Tags: java, codepages

Below I have a small test program than can verify if the content of a **String** is full supported in **codepage** CP852 or not. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
public class CodepageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String test = "æøå123";
            String test2 = new String(test.getBytes("CP852"), "CP852");

            System.out.println(test);
            System.out.println(test2);

            System.out.println("String supported in codepage: " + (test.equals(test2)));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
æøå123
???123
String supported in codepage: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an encoder corresponding to your charset explicitly and use [its `canEncode` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#canEncode%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
boolean canEncode = Charset.forName("CP852").newEncoder().canEncode(test);
```